# how to rename multiple files in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I'd like to rename multiple files in one directory using shell scripting 
the files have common prefix :

```
Modify: 2014-09-19 16:08:35.000000000 +0300-16:08:35.000000000-OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d04_20140919_155335.csv
Modify: 2014-09-19 16:09:23.000000000 +0300-16:09:23.000000000-OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d01_20140919_155423.csv
Modify: 2014-09-19 16:09:51.000000000 +0300-16:09:51.000000000-OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d09_20140919_155451.csv
Modify: 2014-09-19 16:12:40.000000000 +0300-16:12:40.000000000-OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d07_20140919_155740.csv
Modify: 2014-09-19 16:14:48.000000000 +0300-16:14:48.000000000-OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d05_20140919_155948.csv
Modify: 2014-09-19 16:18:14.000000000 +0300-16:18:14.000000000-OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d03_20140919_160314.csv
Modify: 2014-09-19 16:18:15.000000000 +0300-16:18:15.000000000-OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d08_20140919_160315.csv
```

i want to remove the following part from all files :

> Modify: 2014-09-19 16:08:35.000000000 +0300-16:08:35.000000000-

so the output can be like this :

> OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d01_20140423_223805.csv
>   OCS_dmobfw1-oam_d01_20140423_223905.csv

i tried :

```
 for name in Modify* ;
do
 mv "$name"  $(echo $name | sed 's/Modify: 2014-09-19 16:18:14.000000000 +0300-16:18:14.000000000-/ /g') ;
done
```

Comment: You did not tell us what was the problem with you approach but since your file names contain spaces (don't do that), you'll be in troubles.  Using `find` will probably be the safest option.

Comment: could you please tell me more about how to use find in my situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
for name in Modify*
do
    echo mv "$name" "$(sed -E 's/Modify: .{55}//'<<<"$name")"
done
```

remove the echo if satisfied..

The `<<<` is bash extension, if you don't have `bash` use

```
    echo mv "$name" "$(echo "$name" | sed -E 's/Modify: .{55}//')"
```

If every file contains the `OCS`, you could use the shorter:

```
    echo mv "$name" "$(grep -o 'OCS.*' <<<"$name")"
```

Comment: the last edit is working fine thanks but the first two aren't working .

Comment: @MohamedYasser in this case, your sed doesn't knows the `-E`. The _aren't working_ isn't helpful, would be good to know what is the error - for correcting...

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in Modify* ;
do
    new=`echo $name | sed 's/Modify: 2014-09-19 16:18:14.000000000 +0300-16:18:14.000000000-//g'`; 
    mv $name $new;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your accepted answer is probably simpler and at least as good but here is how you might do it using `find`.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'Modify*' -execdir sh -c 'mv -n "$@" "$(echo "$@" | sed "s,Modify: .\{55\},,")";' -- '{}' \;
```

This approach will be most useful if you want to *recurse* into subdirectories.  In that case, remove the `-maxdepth 1` option.

The key problem with your original attempt was that your file names all have different time stamps but you were only replacing a particular one.