# How to rename multiple file extensions at the same time?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, file-rename

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021194/how-to-rename-multiple-files-in-unix) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691608/renaming-multiple-files-in-unix)

I have my filenames like as shown below (1 set contains 3 related files). In my directory, I have 40 set of files (meaning 120 files). All the 40 sets have 3 files with same file extension

**Set 1**

```
Test_t5.version9.info.gz
Test_t5.version9.dose.vcf.gz.tbi
Test_t5.version9.dose.vcf.gz
```

**Set 2**

```
Test_t5.version12.info.gz
Test_t5.version12.dose.vcf.gz.tbi
Test_t5.version12.dose.vcf.gz
```

Only the version number in file changes across different sets.

Now, I would like to rename my files like as shown below

**Set 1**

```
Test_t5.version9.info.gz
Test_t5.version9.dose.vcf.gz.tbi
Test_t5.version9.dose.vcf.bgz            #see the change here from `.gz to .bgz`
```

**Set 2**

```
Test_t5.version12.info.gz
Test_t5.version12.dose.vcf.gz.tbi
Test_t5.version12.dose.vcf.bgz            #see the change here from `.gz to .bgz`
```

I tried the below but guess am making mistake while executing the command in the shell.

```
 rename 's/dose.vcf.gz/dose.vcf.bgz/' Test_t5.version*.dose.vcf.gz
```

Basically modify the file extension for only one file in each of the set. You don't have to worry about `Set 1` or `Set 2`. That was for you to understand that how our data is grouped.

Can you help please?

Comment: That command looks fine to me. Does it produce any output or error messages, or does it silently do nothing?

Comment: no output for my command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are just wanting to do:

```
for file in *.vcf.gz; do mv "$file" "${file%.gz}.bgz"; done
```

Comment: @Thomas You can test what files it will touch by changing the command slightly: `for file in *.vcf.gz; do echo "$file"; done`.  It should not touch any `.info.gz` files.

Comment: It will not touch files with `vcf.gz.tbi` extension. Am I right?

Comment: I only like to rename files with extension `vcf.gz` to `vcf.bgz`

Comment: btw, upvoted for the help. Will accept the answer soon once I try it. Currently not at my desk. but can help me with my questions in the comments

Comment: Correct, the `*.vcf.gz` glob will not match names ending in `vcf.gz.tbi`